# Reproduce random numbers in C# reusing the same initial seed value across differing architectures?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I want to run a scientific experiment which requires random numbers.  However, the random numbers must be reproducible, since a scientific experiment's result set must be able to be reproduced for verification/validation and use by others.

Note: I do not need any special/secure random numbers, simple pseudo-random numbers are perfectly acceptable.

In C#, it is possible to seed the Random Number Generator.  However, will seeding the random number generator (with the same value) produce the same set of random numbers:

1. Across different machines?
2. Across different operating systems?
3. Across different versions of .NET or C#?

Obviously there is a solution, which is to record the set of random numbers and publish it with my experiment, but that seems excessive and I wonder whether it is really necessary.

I am interested in both documented and actual real world usage.  (i.e. if documentation states one thing, but real world usage shows something else).

Comment: "Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers. This is often done when testing apps that rely on random number generators." - [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why don't you test? I'd imagine it takes 1 minute to test on 2 machines, for example

Comment: That section of text from the documentation makes me think it was designed to purposefully keep the numbers the same independent of any system changes.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto because my small test wouldn't reflect reality (two machines isn't enough to justify such an assertion).  Nor do I have access to multiple machines.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I doubt that this is actually guaranteed. The best bet is to write your own. Not that hard..

Comment: Though, if you need to guarantee that they are the same, then I would look elsewhere. The answers and comments in the duplicate indicate that it is not guaranteed from version changes.

Comment: For such cases, the Mersenne Twister is probably what you want